# How can I place a View under another View programmatically in RelativeyLayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

If I add two `View` to the `RelativeLayout`, the newer one overlaps the older one. But for some reasons, I cannot add the `View` that I want to place at the bottom first. Could anyone tell me how I can solve this?

```
RelativeLayout rela = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(...);
rela.addView(v1);
rela.addView(v2);
```

I want `v1` to **OVERLAP** `v2`. I cannot use other `Layout` because this is one part of a large project.

Comment: Are you adding view in xml file or programmed ?

Comment: @SubramanianR Programmatically

Comment: Please post some code what ever you done ....?

Comment: Fine. Then you need to set the layout param for your view .

Comment: use vertical LinearLayout rather RelativeLayout

Comment: @SubramanianR I don't know how I can do that...

Answer (score 1):

Since I have not got a correct answer. I have to rewrite the whole program. This is what I did:
I added `v2` first, and then `v1`. Then I just set the visibility of `v1` to `View.Gone`. I do not know if there is a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add  view over other view....Then u can use FrameLayout.... Within RelativeLayout...
hope this will help u...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a view on bottom of other view. You can use LinearLayout (in vertical). But if you want to add view to bottom of RelativeLayout. Try this:

First, your RelativeLayout needs an ID if you want to reference it:

```
RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourRelativeId);
```

Then create some LayoutParams for the object (in this case, your admob adview) that tell it to align itself to the bottom (and not align to any other views, this way it isn't pushed off-screen or moved by the other views):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rLParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 1);
```

Next, add the view to your RelativeLayout with your LayoutParams:

```
rLayout.addView(yourAdView, rLParams);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I meant under..not below.Is it possible. We are talking about different directions in space xD

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Rule` to your `RelativeLayout`. Say for ex:

```
   p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, existingView.getId());
```

The above rule will allign the new view below the existing view. 
You can read more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)